# Toggle Service via ToggleButton for GPS Tracker

Tags: android, service, android-service, togglebutton

i'm currently writing an app that should to the following:

- The UI only contains one toggle button. If it is turned on the GPS Position shall be sent to an external server. If it is turned off, nothing shall happen.
- If the Button was turned on and the app (activity) is closed the location should still be send until the Button is turned off again.

How can i achieve this ? I read a lot of threads and tutorials and on dev.google.com, but i was not able to find the best solution for my problem.

My current approach:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if (onOffButton.isChecked()) {
      Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
      startService(startIntent);
   } else {
      stopService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
   }
}
```

**LocationService.java**

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

        final public static String START_ACTION = "START_LOCATION";
        final public static int NOTE_ID = 1;

        private int updateRate;

        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private NotificationManager notifyManager;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
                super.onStart(intent, startId);

                // show popup message
                Toast.makeText(this, getText(R.string.start_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // display icon in status bar

                requestLocationUpdates();
        }

        private void requestLocationUpdates() {
                if(locationManager != null)
                        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

                // get location service
                Criteria crit = new Criteria();
                crit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                String bestProvider = getLocationManager().getBestProvider(crit, true);
                getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, updateRate * 1000,
                                0 /* minDist */, this);

                LocationService.running = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                getLocationManager().removeUpdates(this);
                notifyManager.cancel(NOTE_ID);
                Toast.makeText(this, getText(R.string.stop_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                LocationService.running = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                //Send Location to Server
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO stop service, notify user
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                requestLocationUpdates();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO notify user
        }

        private LocationManager getLocationManager() {
                if (this.locationManager == null)
                        this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                return this.locationManager;
        }
}
```

I got this from a very old gps tracker i found on the Internet (i know that onStart() is deprecated and should replaced with onCommandStart()) I just want to know if the general approach is good..

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The approach looks fine.  You just need to implement the call-back methods to report your location.